# Android Studio Upgrade to 0.1.3 Failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to upgrade Android Studio from 0.1.2 to 0.1.3 on Windows 8.  The patch file downloads, extracts and validates, but then I get a `'Failed to apply patch'` message: `'java.io.IOException: Cannot delete file C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\lib\netty-3.6.3.Final.jar'`.  I'm running the upgrade from within Android Studio, which I'm running as an administrator.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by

1. uninstalling Android Studio via un-installer and
2. by removing all files from the installation folder left over by by the un-installer.
3. by re-running the initial installer.
4. starting the app as admin and execute the updates.

I had the same issue before in my environment:

- Win 7 64 bit + JAVA_HOME pointing to JDK 7 32 bit
- My current version: 0.1.2 Build 130.692269
- My version to be: 0.1.9 Build 130.729444

Note: Android studio does not appear to run at all if I do not use a JDK V7 and if I do not use a 32 bit JDK.

The issue could not be resolved by the following approaches:
 - Start Android studio as adminstrator
 - Provide full access rights to the folder

Answer (score 0):

The above did not fix the problem for me. I eventually pointed to the folder where the issue was coming up (D:\Program Files (x86)\Android\Android Studio\plugins\gradle for my installation). I changed the permission for "users" to "Full control" in the security tab. Ran AS as administrator and selected update under the Help menu. I'm the only person who uses my machine, so I don't believe this is a security risk.